# Why is this natural language sentence written in a formal predicate language the way it is here?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I have this sentence: "All teachers and students are here." Also I have these predicates: t(x) - x are teachers, s(x) - x are students, h(x) - x are here. In my textbook the sentence is written in a predicate language this way: $\forall x((s(x)∨t(x))\to h(x)$ .

The question is: Why there is OR symbol instead of AND symbol?

Comment: x can either be a teacher or a student, but not both

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!

Comment: Note this is equivalent to $(\forall x)(t(x)\implies h(x)) \land (\forall x)(s(x)\implies h(x))$ which contains "and".

Answer (score 2):

An "and" here would mean "for every $x$, if $x$ is a teacher and $x$ is a student, then $x$ is here". In English the "and" is intended as a union, which is expressed in logic as "or".

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic. The one I always use is 'All fruits and vegetable are nutritious'

So yes, given the 'and', you might be inclined to symbolize "All teachers and students are here" as:

$$\forall x ((T(x) \land S(x)) \to H(x))$$

but that would mean that "Anyone who is both a teacher and a student is here"

So, what's going on? Why doesn't the 'and' in English give you the logical $\land$?

It's because "All teachers and students are here" is really short for "All teachers are here and all students are here".

Indeed, we could translate this sentence as:

$$\forall x (T(x) \to H(x)) \land \forall x (S(x) \to H(x)) $$

which is equivalent to:

$$\forall x ((T(x) \to H(x) \land (S(x) \to H(x)) $$

And now, here is the crucial equivalence that swithces the $\land$ into an $\lor$:

$$(P \lor Q) \to R \Leftrightarrow (P \to R) \land (Q \to R)$$

So with that, we can symbolize the sentence also as:

$$\forall x ((T(x) \lor S(x)) \to H(x))$$

and if we translate that back to English, we get:

"Anyone who is  a teacher or a student is here"

which is, if you think about it, exactly what we want!